# A Process to check if Infinite Loop is still running in Python3

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, networking

I am unable to grasp this with the help of Programming concepts in general with the following scenario:

**Note:** All Data transmission in this scenario is done via UDP packets using `socket` module of **Python3**

- I have a **Server** which sends some certain amount of data, assume **300 Packets** over a WiFi Channel
- At the other end, I have a receiver which works on a certain *Decoding process* to decode the data. This *Decoding Process* is kind of Infinite Loop which returns Boolean Value `true` or `false` at every iteration depending on certain aspects which can be neglected as of now

a Rough Code Snippet is as follows:**Python3**

```
incomingPacket = next(bringNextFromBuffer)

if decoder.consume_data(incomingPacket):
    # this if condition is inside an infinite loop
    # unless the if condition becomes True keep
    # keep consuming data in a forever for loop

    print("Data has been received")
```

Everything as of moment works since the Server and Client are in proximity and the data can be decoded. But in practical scenarios I want to check the loop that is mentioned above. For instance, after a certain amount of time, if the above loop is still in the *Forever (Infinite) state* I would like to send out something back to the server to start the data sending again.

I am not much clear with *multithreading* concept, but can I use a thread over here in this scenario?

For Example:

- Thread a Process for a certain amount of time and keep checking the `decoder.consume_data()` function and if the time expires and the output is still `False` can I then send out a kind of **Feedback** to the server using `struct.pack()` over sockets.

Of course the networking logic, need **NOT** be addressed as of now. But is python capable of *MONITORING THIS INFINITE LOOP VIA A PARALLEL THREAD OR OTHER CONCEPT OF PROGRAMMING*?

#### Caveats

Unfortunately the Receiver in question is a dumb receiver i.e. No user control is specified. Only thing Receiver can do is decode the data and perhaps send a **Feedback** to the Server stating whether the data is received or not and that is possible only when the above mentioned **LOOP** is completed.

What is a possible solution here?
(Would be happy to share more information on request)

Comment: as an abstract: `is_running_inf_loop = True ; while True: do_stuff_that_could_stop_loop() ; is_running_inf_loop = False` any kind threading checking part will at some point boil down to this, although it might be better to use some sort of [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#lock-objects) instead of a boolean.

Comment: This is a rather confusing question. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Design and implement a reliable transfer protocol on top of UDP?

Comment: Hello @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I somehow get the part, sadly the above mentioned function is a module that I am using from someone else. If I understand you correctly I would __LOCK__ the present infinite state and when the thread is executed I __UNLOCK__ the infinite loop.

Comment: @o9000 No achieving reliability using a FEC method called __FountainCodes__ in Wireless Environment using __LT-Codes__. I would like to give the option of __HARQ__ (Hybrid ARQ) which inculcates FEC and ARQ together.
Also Imagine, other receivers decode the data but there might be one receiver who might need to a little more data again from the Server to as to decode the remaining data. For that this lone Receiver might __LOCK__ the present state send a small feedback out and then go back into *Infinite state*

Comment: "one receiver who might need to a little more data again" Maybe some sort of timeout is what you need?

Comment: @o9000 I cannot join the dots here. For instance, the __300 packets__ are sent, the Server stops sending it but anticipates an ACK on the socket. What will a timeout at the receiver serve?

If you wish I can share the GitHub Project of mine and the modules I am using. To clear things out more.

Comment: How would another thread know, then?

Comment: Ah, yes! Now I understand. Exactly what you mentioned. A __TIMEOUT__ is maybe the right thing. For instance, if the Timeout is triggered I would send an ACK out. @o9000

Comment: I don't know exactly because I am not familiar with this protocol. But what you seem to be doing here is implementing a state machine with an event loop. It's a very common design pattern. Only a single thread is required. For timers, see for instance https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.timeout

Comment: Thank you will have a look at the link. Thanks again. @o9000

Comment: You're welcome. One more thing. It might be helpful to draw on paper the full state machine with all the possible transitions, before trying to implement it. See for example http://archive.cone.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/lecture/protocol-design-s09/slides/04-Protocol_Specification_1.pdf

Comment: Yes thank you will draw a FSM and come up with something concrete and let you know. @o9000

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Roughly it'll look like this:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

state = 'running'

def monitor():
    while True:
        if state == 'running':
            tell_client()
            sleep(1)  # to prevent too much happening here

Thread(target=monitor).start()

while state == 'running':
    receive_data()
```

Comment: Hello, I will give it a try and give a feedback with this. Thanks

Comment: hello can I use `asyncio` here?  like an event loop to check is still running or not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about asyncio.